# dictionary - Fedora Linux

Tags: linux, dictionary, terminal, fedora

I'm kind of new to Linux, and heard of what is called `dictionary`. What is that? And how can I navigate to it from `Terminal`?

Thanks.

Comment: Not seeing a programming question here.

Answer (score 2):

A [dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary) is a collection of words of a given language, either with definitions or translations, in order to facilitate learning the language or to widen one's vocabulary.

**Edit:** As @Paul Tomblin pointed out, you can navigate to it by getting up from your desk and going over to your bookshelf.

Comment: And you navigate to it by getting up from your desk and going over to your bookshelf.

Comment: @PaulTomblin well spotted! May I add that to the answer?

Comment: @PaulTomblin Thanks for the useful information. Perhaps citing the C standard would also be relevant.